# Google Spreadsheet Drop Down Matrix

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to make an HR performance in excel, and I created a drop-down list on A2:A11 and B2:B11. What I want to do is, based on the Conditions that will be met, it will be displayed automatically on cells C2:C11.

[image: Here is the screenshot of my sheet]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @player0: [tag:formula] is for mathematical equations, not for spreadsheet formulas.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AND(OR(A2="Exceeds",A2="Partially Exceeds",A2="Meets",A2="Partialy Meets",A2="Below"),B2="Does not Demonstrate"),"Unsatisfactory Performance",
 IF(AND(OR(A2="Exceeds",A2="Partially Exceeds"),B2="Seldom Demonstrates"),"Solid Performance",
 IF(AND(OR(A2="Partialy Meets",A2="Below"),B2="Seldom Demonstrates"),"Unsatisfactory Performance",
 IF(AND(A2="Meets",B2="Seldom Demonstrates"),"Partially Met Performance",
 IF(AND(OR(A2="Exceeds",A2="Partially Exceeds"),B2="Frequently Demonstrates"),"Strong Performance",
 IF(AND(OR(A2="Partialy Meets",A2="Below"),B2="Frequently Demonstrates"),"Strong Performance",
 IF(AND(A2="Meets",B2="Frequently Demonstrates"),"Solid Performance",
 IF(AND(A2="Exceeds",B2="Consistently Demonstrates"),"Outstanding Performance",
 IF(AND(A2="Partialy Exceeds",B2="Consistently Demonstrates"),"Strong Performance",
 IF(AND(A2="Meets",B2="Consistently Demonstrates"),"Solid Performance",
 IF(AND(A2="Partialy Meets",B2="Consistently Demonstrates"),"Partially Met Performance",
 IF(AND(A2="Below",B2="Consistently Demonstrates"),"Unsatisfactory Performance",))))))))))))
```

[image: 4]